# How to call Stored procedure in DTS defined on a sql server and use output parameter value as i/p to stored procedure in different SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have created a stored procedure suppose sp_1 on a server say server1 and i want to use the output of this procedure as a input to another stored procedure defined in another server say server2.

I am creating a DTS package for this using DTS designer. What would be my steps to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2000 DTS or are you using SSIS? Big, big difference.

Comment: I am using 2008r2 SSMS. Went to Management, legacy, Data transformation services. I have edited the previous DTS package from 'Open package file' option. It was opened in DTS designer. I am working on that.

Answer (score 0):

In DTS you can do:

```
EXEC dbo.proc1 ?, ?
```

DTS is going away (Its not supported in 2012 and on). For your sake and others who will have to maintain your code learn SSIS which is what you want to use. In SSIS you can use an OLE DB command which has input and output parameters.